# ng-bootstrap DatePicker set startDate and minDate on trigger Angular 4

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-template

So, I'm using ng-bootstrap DatePicker, and have two forms, startDate and endDate
I need to be able to do 2 things with this:

- when render the "create page" put today's date on startDate, if render "edit page", put the date from the backend..
- when selected the startDate, trigger the minDate attribute to be the selected startDate

Here's how I'm trying to do(with hardcode now, not getting the data from the backend)

```
export class ProgramFormComponent {
  startDate: NgbDateStruct;
  endDate: NgbDateStruct;
  minEndDate: NgbDateStruct;

  programInput = {
    'viewType' : 'Create',
    'programTitle' : '',
    'programDescription' : '',
    'programOwner' : [
        ''
      ],
    'changepointID' : '',
    'startDate' : this.startDate,
    'endDate' : this.endDate,
    'minDate' : this.minEndDate
  }

  programInputEdit = {
    'viewType' : 'Edit',
    'programTitle' : 'Test Title',
    'programDescription' : 'Test Description',
    'programOwner' : [
        'Test Owner 1',
        'Test Owner 2',
        'Test Owner 3',
      ],
    'changepointID' : 'ID',
    'startDate' : this.startDate,
    'endDate' : this.endDate,
    'minDate' : this.minEndDate
  }

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
    if (this.programInput['viewType'] === 'Create') {
        this.selectToday();
    } else {
        this.startDate = {year: 2017, month: 7, day: 1};
        this.endDate = {year: 2017, month: 12, day: 2};
    }
  }

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { windowClass: 'dark-modal' });
  }

  selectToday() {
    this.startDate = {year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
  }

  limitEndDate() {
    this.minEndDate = this.startDate;
  }

<form>
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="startDate" class="control-label">Start Date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                     name="startDate" [(ngModel)]="programInput.startDate" ngbDatepicker #s="ngbDatepicker" firstDayOfTheWeek=1 [startDate]="programInput.startDate">
                <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="s.toggle()" >
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="startDate" class="control-label">End Date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                     name="startDate" [(ngModel)]="programInput.endDate" ngbDatepicker #e="ngbDatepicker" [minDate]="programInput.minEndDate">
                <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="e.toggle()" >
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

also, if someone know how to do it, I want the popup display of the calendar to be on the direction of the top of the page, not the bottom...didn't find any attribute to set this.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this without the property `minDate`, but if you need it, you can do the following. I have introduced a new variable `dataToBeUsed` (name appropriately) to be the variable we use, so take that in consideration in this example compared to your code.

First question, you wanted to check if this is `Create` or 'something else'. I prefer to do initial things in `OnInit` instead of constructor. You mentioned that you will get your data from backend if the `viewType` is not `'Create'`, so....

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.programInput['viewType'] === 'Create') {
    // remember objects are mutable
    this.dataToBeUsed = this.programInput;
    this.dataToBeUsed.startDate = {year: new Date().getFullYear(), month: new Date().getMonth() + 1, day: new Date().getDate()};
  } else {
    this.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataToBeUsed = data;
      })
  }    
}
```

you wanted to change the `minDate` when your start date changes. So let's make use of `ngModelChange` (rest omitted)

```ts
<input (ngModelChange)="setMinDate($event)" [(ngModel)]="dataToBeUsed.startDate">
```

`setMinDate` method:

```ts
setMinDate(event) {
  this.dataToBeUsed.minDate = event;
}
```

From your code, I have removed the variables

```ts
startDate, endDate, minEndDate
```

since I see no use for them. We can just refer to the same attributes in the `dataToBeUsed` object.

so for the second date-picker, where you want to disable dates that are before your startdate, we mark it as:

```ts
[minDate]="dataToBeUsed.minDate"
```

Here's a plunker for your reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/zfGUrMJkJzQXTBJ86OSs?p=preview

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that! :) :)